# Why do I have to set MySQL user password with mysql_native_password to connect with Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, authentication, mysql-8.0

I've noticed if I set the mysql user's password like below, I cannot connect with MySQL Workbench.
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPassword'`

If I use this below I can connect to it:
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'myPassword';`

I remember at MySQL 8 there was a default password policy change.
But still after years of that change, do the drivers (*c/c++, node.js etc*) not support the new password authentication?
Does MySQL's own Workbench don't support the new way of authentication?
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL Workbench 8** accepts, if mysql server is set to legacy mode, also native_passwords.

But it  also accepts users that use cashing_sha2_password or sh2 passwords.

So you must check the users roles and for which. first try to use `%` in `LImit to host matching` and DBA as role, so that your user has all privileges to test.

Comment: I am still confused. Limit to Hosts matching setting is a setting from where someone can connect as this user; localhost or a specific IP or public internet... How is it related to the password encryption method?

Comment: it has nothing to do with the password setting, but ypou clained that it will not work, so i gave you hints to find the source of the problem